# Reactive Extension databinding

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I apologize for asking a n00b question, but I'm only just learning about Rx, and I'm unclear about a way it is supposed to be used.

I understand Rx is about observables and if I would like to subscribe to some observable values entered in a few text and checkboxes which in turn could affect an enabled state of a button, how would I best go about that, is there a way to databind to an observable?

From what I gather from some examples I've looked at so far, most make LINQ queries that query values which are in the text(and check?)boxes and then they set properties of controls programmatically and not by direct databinding, is that right? If that is the case how do you query those values please? An small example would be awesome please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea in that control properties are generally directly or indirectly set imperatively from Rx observers' OnNext handlers. (I say indirectly because it's probably better to update an INPC property on your ViewModel and bind to that).

I think your best bet is to walk through the lab the Rx team provided here - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208528. It will probably take you around an hour or so, but it's very well explained and worth the enlightenment it will bring, and it covers this sort of thing with a console and winforms example.

After you've read this, the following should make sense:

Create a stream from the textbox and/or checkbox events using Observable.FromEventPattern and then subscribe to this and update your Button enabled state (or an INPC property it binds to) in the OnNext handler.